# Addressing USB-Stick by UUID as kernel parameter in grub.cfg

Tags: arch-linux, grub, luks, dm-crypt, kernel-parameters

I'm using Arch Linux and setting up an USB-Stick as decryption key for my luks-encrypted root partition (boot is unencrypted). I described it already in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/517874/348087).

Now, the key, that's used for dm-crypt is actually stored **before** the first partition on the stick, created this way:

`sudo dd if=tempKey.bin of=/dev/sdd bs=512 seek=1 count=6`

thus, 3072 are written into sector 1..6 (zero indexed). When I use the following kernel parameter in `grub.cfg` it works:

`cryptkey=/dev/sdd:512:3072`

But I cannot rely on that stick always being mapped to sdd, thatswhy even Arch-Wiki recommends using the disks ID, namely:

`cryptkey=/dev/disk/by-id/$ID_OF_USB_STICK$:512:3072`

BUT: USB-Sticks are getting IDs that contain colons and so the device is not found on boot, even if I try to escape the colon with a backslash. The system always seems to look for the ID before the colon.

Using `cryptkey=UUID=...` would only work, if I use space/sector **inside** a partition, not before or between.

So, I'm really stuck here. Someone any suggestions, how to solve this without rely on sdX and the possibility to accidentally overwrite/delete the key by putting it inside a partition? Would it be an option to manipulate `rules.d` of `udev` to change the way the IDs(and symlinks) for USB-Sticks are created?

Answer (score 0):

If the device path you want to access contains the character `:`, you have to escape it with a backslash `\`. In that case the `cryptkey` parameter would be as follow: `cryptkey=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-123456-0\:0:0:512` for a USB key with the id `usb-123456-0:0`.